# MongoDB set field in array of embedded documents to value of another field

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Within my document I have an array of embedded documents. I want to set the value of one field from one of the documents in the array to the value of another field, outside the array but in the same parent document.

Doing this, I can set the value to a constant (4).

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: 1, "arr.elem": 2}, {$set:{"arr.$.newField": 4}})
```

But if I try to set it to a field value, it stores `"$topLevelField"` as a *string literal value.*

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: 1, "arr.elem": 2}, {$set:{"arr.$.newField": "$topLevelField"}})
```

This sets `Newfield` to `topLevelField` like I want, but it doesn't limit it to where `arr.elem == 2`, instead applying it to *every* `newField` element in the array.

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1, "arr.elem": 2}, [{$set:{"arr.newField": "$topLevelField"}}])
```

I'm using version 7.0.0
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input data and desired result.